# Find out when and who added a site to our Google Analytics portal?

Tags: google-analytics

We have several sites and users on our portal, and I'd like to be able to find out who "owns" each site, as well as when they added the site. Is this possible in the portal somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the GA account in question > go to the admin panel > on the far left, click on "Change History" > you should be able to see all account-level actions for that particular account here, including when permissions were assigned to certain users and who has "management" permissions.